# Java: Taking a Image and turning it into Black in White with RGB

Tags: java

So I am doing a group project for my programming class, we are makeing a photo editing program and one of my parts of the program is taking the image and turning it into black and white using rgb. I was wondering what would be the best value or way in RGB to achieve black and white?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend letting the Java 2D library worry about the conversion:

- create a greyscale BufferedImage (BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
- get a graphics context by createGraphics()
- ensure that colour rendering is accurate on that graphics context: call setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY)
- draw the colour image you want to "convert" to the graphics context

If you do the conversion "manually" and you want to do it as accurately as possible, then you need to take into account that the eye is more sensitive to certain colour components than others. (If you want a "rough and ready" conversion, you can average the colour components, but this isn't strictly speaking the most accurate conversion.)

Answer (score 2):

For each pixel, you can convert the RGB to HSB (using `Color.RGBtoHSB`), set the saturation to 0, and convert back to a Color instance using `Color.getHSBColor`.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) actually has a good piece about how to perform the transformation once you have the RGB colors.

Comment: In addition to Wikipedia, see this [C# implementation](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale) with some neat explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey , this [page](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) has many Java Image filters which are freely available for download.All filters are standard Java `BufferedImageOps` and can be plugged directly into existing programs.The `GrayscaleFilter` can convert the image to black and white

Answer (score 0):

Using [`java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html) with a gray destination `ColorSpace` is very efficient. There's an excellent example [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/d4c436ab64d4ced4).